# How do I change a bulb in this flush mounted light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I need to replace the bulb in this flush mounted ceiling light with a glass dome but cannot open it. There are two handles (springs?) that I assume should be used to achieve that but I could not figure the system out. I tried pushing on them upwards or pulling to the side but no luck. I have tried rotating the glass dome but that does not loosen it.
Any ideas?

[image: image of full light fuxture]
[image: right handle (spring?)]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do those handles move at all? Have you tried just a moderate pull straight down on the glass?

Comment: Looking at the 2nd photo it looks like the handle may be able to be pushed in. That may just be paint that has scraped off but you have tried the normal things.

Comment: @EdBeal your idea with the handle did not work but was a very good hit in the right direction... Instead of pushing in, I pulled them out which released the glass dome.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was inspired by Ed Beal's idea. 
Pulling both handles out released the glass dome. Each handle can be pulled out separately to help keep the dome from falling.

Comment: I figured you had tried out glad you got it.